# Solving for $ \lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} (x^3-1)\ln{(1-x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm trying to solve :

$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} (x^3-1)\ln{(1-x)}$$

I've checked with wolfram and the answer appears to be 0. However, no step-by-step is given and I can't figure out how to end with 0.

I think it might be $(x^3-1)$ equals to $0$ for $x = 1^-$, then $\ln{(1-x)}$ equals to $\infty$ for $x = 1^-$ then $0 * \infty$ would gives $0$, but I doubt it is that simple because the homework's goal is to solve undeterminated forms using L'Hospital's rule.

Am I missing something or the answer really is $0$ ? And if it is, is my explanation good or just an hazard ?

**Edit :** I think I just found out how I can easily solve it in another way then what is explained in the answers. I'd like it if someone could confirm my solution is valid.

I convert $$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} (x^3-1)\ln{(1-x)}$$ to $$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{(x^3-1)}{\frac{1}{\ln{(1-x)}}}$$ which gives me a form of $\frac{0}{0}$ Then I use L'Hospital which gives me $$ \lim_{x\to 1^-} \frac{3x^2}{\frac{x}{1-x}}$$ which equals 0.

Is my solution correct ?

Comment: $0\cdot\infty$ can be anything in $[0, \infty]$.

Comment: @Nishant Actually it can be anything in $(-\infty,\infty)$ (negative if $0$ is approached from the "left").

Comment: Oh, right. My bad.

Answer (score 6):

Notice that 
$$x^3-1=-(1-x)(x^2+x+1)$$
and recall that

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+}y\ln y=0$$
so change the variable $y=1-x$ and the result follows easily.

Comment: What happen with the $(x^2+x+1)$ ? And also why the limit now is as y approchaes 0 ?

Comment: @ProgrammerJeff The limit of $x^2+x+1$ is $3$, and $3\cdot0=0$.

Comment: There's no problem with the factor $x^2+x+1$ just change the variable and it becomes $(y-1)^2+(y-1)+1$. To see why the limit of $y\ln y$ is $0$ write it on this form
$$\frac{\ln y}{\frac1y}$$
and then use the L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $\dfrac {\ln y}{1/y}$?

Comment: Yes. Thanks @GFauxPas ${}$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane would you please check my edit and tell me if my solution is correct ?

Comment: @ProgrammerJeff It isn't correct! What's the derivative of 
$$\frac1{\ln(1-x)}\qquad?$$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane $\frac{-1}{1-x}$ ?

Comment: No this the derivative of $\ln(1-x)$ and this is your mistake. The derivative of $\frac 1f$ is $-\frac {f'}{f^2}$ where $f$ is a given function.@ProgrammerJeff

Comment: My bad. Then it is $\frac{\frac{-1}{1-x}}{(\ln{(1-x)})^2}$ @SamiBenRomdhane